# iOS7 not loading css image with height over 1950px

Tags: ios, css, image, ios7, background-image

I have a css image that has a height of 2000px that fails to load on iOS7 devices - I have tried out different heights and found that 1949px works and 1950px doesn't.

I have used a few different images and found it is defiantly the height thats making it fail to load rather than file size.

Does anyone have any idea why the image(s) would fail to load on iOS7?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Safari Dev library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) there is a limit due to memory available on the device.

Under **Know iOS Resource Limits**

> The maximum size for decoded GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels for devices with less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM.
>
> That is, ensure that width * height ≤ 3 * 1024 * 1024 for devices with less than 256 MB RAM. Note that the decoded size is far larger than the encoded size of an image.
>
> The maximum decoded image size for JPEG is 32 megapixels using subsampling.

So it's probably actually down to file size rather than actual height and width.

Comment: I don't think its to do with that: I've looked at the http response and request, for the 1949px image (2688x1949) the decoded data is 484.18kb (loads fine) and the 1950px (2690x1950) decoded data is 484.63kb (doesn't load)